# XP blue screens on installer on my pc

Tags: windows-xp, boot, multi-boot, windows-installation

I currently have my laptop running on windows 7. I plan on adding XP and keeping permanently disconnected from the internet to run some old games/programs (My pc doesn't have much ram so vm's are not good). I found a guide on dual booting but when I boot from the XP CD I immediately get a BSOD I am able to get into win 7 easily but not into the installer. I also wish to add ubuntu any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Uhh, what happens in the BSOD? Do you know the order to install the OSes in?

Comment: For the installation sequence, first XP then Win7 then Ubuntu. And what do you mean by `I am able to get into Win7 easily but not the installer`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest two different avenues of approach to your problem of running XP apps...I think that dual boot can be problematic and generally try to stay away from this type of situation.

There is XP mode available for Windows 7 that allows you to run XP apps on Win 7 by basically running a MS virtual machine with XP.  XP mode software is M$ supported and available somewhere in their website.

Another alternative, assuming you have the appropriate legal license key, is to run this under VMWare workstation or try it on VirtualBox if you dare.  I personally have been running XP under VMWare for quite some time.

Although it has been awhile since I used it Wine under linux (Ubuntu) might also be an alternative to run your older applications.  Of course under Linux you can also run visualization (either vmware or another variant).

Comment: I do have a legit key but vmware runs to slow I would use the xp mode but I have win 7 home premium. When I try to boot xp cd i get BSOD

Answer (score 0):

Search Google for "Mini Windows XP" and make a bootable.

Otherwise:

Your machine is updated enough to properly run Windows 7, which is fantastic. The problem lies with your hardware in the machine. Windows XP is no longer a supported OS, this means that hardware is not being built to allow Windows XP to run on it, only newer and more resource heavy OS's, like Windows 7.

The only way you're going to get XP to run on your computer is if you rebuild it with XP compatible hardware, which is a downgrade. Try a repair shop or something, see if they have any old machines that can run XP for you or buy an upgraded version of Windows 7 to run XP mode. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

It would cost more but you could upgrade your machine or replace it with a better one, to run a VM.

Comment: I managed to run it had to enable IDE in my bios my laptop was built in 2009 so it has support. Just a problem everytime I want to boot into XP I have to change the BIOS to IDE and when I want windows 7 I need to change it to AHCI. Is there some sort of registry hack for XP I could use to make XP boot even if ACHI is enabled I would really like to simplify this issue.